# How to perform operations on pairs of rows, based on a "distinguishing" column's values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with two rows for each unique combination of values across multiple index columns, which are distinguished by the values in another column. For example (and here the "index" values are `color` and `hue`, and the "distinguishing" value is `level`:

```
color = rep(c("r", "g", "b"), each=4) 
hue = rep(rep(c("l", "d"), each=2), 3) 
level = rep(1:2, 6) 
val = c(2, 4, 4, 8, 1, 9, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2, 9) 
df = data.frame(color, hue, level, val) 
df
   color hue level val
1      r   l     1   2
2      r   l     2   4
3      r   d     1   4
4      r   d     2   8
5      g   l     1   1
6      g   l     2   9
7      g   d     1   4
8      g   d     2   7
9      b   l     1   3
10     b   l     2   4
11     b   d     1   2
12     b   d     2   9
```

In the above example, I'd like to create a new data frame containing, for each unique combination of `color` and `hue`,  the difference between the `val`s from the "level 2" row and and the "level 1" row .

That is (created by hand):

```
dfDif
  color hue dif
1     r   l   2
2     r   d   4
3     g   l   8
4     g   d   3
5     b   l   1
6     b   d   7
```

Ideally, I'd like to use dplyr, but that's not a requirement by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(tidyverse)

color = rep(c("r", "g", "b"), each=4) 
hue = rep(rep(c("l", "d"), each=2), 3) 
level = rep(1:2, 6) 
val = c(2, 4, 4, 8, 1, 9, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2, 9) 
df = data.frame(color, hue, level, val) 
df

df_t=pivot_wider(df, names_from = c("level"), values_from = c("val"))
df_t

# df_t[, 'dif'] <- df_t[, 4] - df_t[, 3]
df_t[c("1","2","dif")] <- list(NULL, NULL, df_t[["2"]] - df_t[["1"]]) # From user thelatemail
```

Comment: You could even clean up the other variables at the same time as assigning the result - `df_t[c("1","2","dif")] <- list(NULL, NULL, df_t[["2"]] - df_t[["1"]])`